# Not able to access the userdata property of the sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

In My project i am having 10 sprite,Each one having a unique userData value.During ccTouch method i am copying a sprite to New sprite,

But i cant able to get the sprite userdata value.

My coding is

```
 for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
      {
       CCSprite *zig=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"zig%d.png",i]];
        zig.position=ccp(325,60);
        zig.tag=i+1;
        zig.userData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[zigpositionarray objectAtIndex:i-1]];
        [self addChild:zig z:2];
       [zigblurarray addObject:zig];
            NSLog(@"Userdata%@",zig.userData);
      }
```

In cctouchBegan Method:

```
  for(CCSprite *s in zigblurarray)
  { 
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(s.boundingBox, Newpt1))
   {
       temp=s;
       temp.userData=s.userData;
       NSLog(@"%d",temp.tag);
        NSLog(@"Userdata%@",temp.userData);
    }
```

Finaly i am getting lldb error

0x170409b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi   EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Please any one help me for this problem.

Comment: Is both s.userData and temp.userData empty? Where do you get the error  - at the log statement?

Answer (score 1):

The string is autoreleased. The `userData` property is of type void* and will not retain the object. Use the `userObject` property instead (if available in your cocos2d version) or retain the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning one object to another variable will not copy it. Remember, objects are just represented as pointers to objects.

After

```
temp=s;
```

`temp` also points to `s`.  `t.userData` will already be `s.userData` because they are the same object.

Try

```
temp = [s copy];
```